AWS Kinesis Stream Put Record
aws_templates % aws kinesis put-record --stream-name KenesisStream --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out --data '{"number1":1, "number2":100}' --partition-key 2
How can we define the data, if I want to give numericals in the data? Is it the right way did I pass the values or anything I need to change? I can be able to run this command without any errors, but the data values are not reading by my lambda function it gets invoked when I put the record into the stream kinesis. Also, can anyone suggest how to get records from Kinesis through the aws cli...
Responses are appreciated!!!!!
